# JSON as JavaScript object - security risks

Tags: javascript, json, security

Are there any security risks while using following or is JSON escaped safely?

```
<script>
   var _configuration = %VARIABLE_EXPAND_CONTAINS_JSON%
</script>
```

Comment: if it is strict JSON, you shouldn't have a problem. we need an example of how that value is being placed in.

Comment: For example raw output of http://php.net/json_encode function.

Comment: that should be fine.

Comment: Well, if it is escaped *safely* then there is no security risk. So how do you escape it? Please show us the code that generates `VARIABLE_EXPAND_CONTAINS_JSON`.

Comment: For example, you will need to make sure that `</script>` does not get through in the variable.

Comment: I use pure output from php function json_encode, but it should be escaped right. Everything in quotations and all quotation marks in content are escaped.

Answer (score 1):

If you control the content, probably not. If at any time a user can input part of it - yes, there are tons of risks

Comment: Do you assume that it is not properly escaped, and works only because the "controlled content" does not cause issues?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you are asking why there are risks, its because you will almost always have a user that is smarter, faster, better looking and more malicious then me or yourself, and will do something incredibly clever to get around what you do. As you mentioned above, if it is escaped safely and properly then it should work fine.

Comment: Yeah, however I think it just should be escaped properly in every case, so that it doesn't matter where the content comes from. Escaping is not only done to make user-controlled content safe, but also to prevent yourself from making mistakes. But you're right, the risk comes from the user

Comment: of course, escaping always. That should be assumed. However code used for escaping can have errors in it, and are much more likely to be hit from user submissions then your own code.